# Removing HDD from RAID 5 to pull data from

Tags: linux, raid, raid5

I have a relatively (I think) simple question...

I have a file server with RAID 5 that is old and pretty much dead and I need to grab the data from it. I was thinking I could pull one of the HDD's out and put it into a Linux server so I can mount the drive and copy over the files from it.

Is this possible or do I need to do something to the RAID 5 first to be able to get the data?

Comment: Love it when people vote down and not give a reason to make this better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No single drive in a RAID5 holds all information.

[image: Raid5 info graphics from commons.wikimedia.org]

So removing a single disk and mounting it would not be possible the first place, much less creating a backup from it. You should create a backup of the filesystem in the running array.

Graphic created by [Colin Burnett](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Cburnett)